# Place holders of space for variable width of fonts in String ,java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, placeholder

I want to print two String(Chinese charater) in two line.

Say

```
String1="XXXX"+"词语:"
String2="YY"+"词语:"
```

I want the **"词语:"** will be aligned. So I need some blank spaces added in to left for String if needed.

How can I format this String in a flexible way(I know the max length of the XXXX).
I guess I can use String.format(), but I cannot find the correct place holder.

Updated:

I take some of the answers and found that the solution is not work for chinese in eclipse console:

```
    String english1="xxxx";
    String english2="yy";

    String chinese1="卧卧卧";
    String chinese2="卧";
    int n=english1.length()>english2.length()? english1.length():english2.length();
    int m=chinese1.length()>chinese2.length()? chinese1.length():chinese2.length();

    System.out.println("n="+n);
    System.out.println("m="+m);

    System.out.println(padRight(english1,n)+"end");
    System.out.println(padRight(english2,n)+"end");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println(padRight(chinese1,m)+"end");
    System.out.println(padRight(chinese2,m)+"end");
```

Output:

```
n=4
m=3
xxxxend
  yyend
----------------------------
卧卧卧end
  卧end
```

Chinese padding still have problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Something like...

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-4s %s:", "XXXX", "词语"));
System.out.println(String.format("%-4s %s:", "YY", "词语"));
```

Which prints

```
XXXX 词语:
YY   词语:
```

Or

```
System.out.println(String.format("%4s %s:", "XXXX", "词语"));
System.out.println(String.format("%4s %s:", "YY", "词语"));
```

Which prints

```
XXXX 词语:
  YY 词语:
```

You could then wrap this into a method call and pass the prefix and the suffix to to do the formatting for you

For example...

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatLeftAligned("XXXX", "词语"));
        System.out.println(formatLeftAligned("YY", "词语"));

        System.out.println(formatRightAligned("XXXX", "词语"));
        System.out.println(formatRightAligned("YY", "词语"));

    }

    public static String formatLeftAligned(String prefix, String suffix) {
        return String.format("%-4s %s:", prefix, suffix);
    }

    public static String formatRightAligned(String prefix, String suffix) {
        return String.format("%4s %s:", prefix, suffix);
    }

}
```

Or

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatLeftAligned("XXXX", 4, "词语"));
        System.out.println(formatLeftAligned("YY", 4, "词语"));

        System.out.println(formatRightAligned("XXXX", 4, "词语"));
        System.out.println(formatRightAligned("YY", 4, "词语"));

    }

    public static String formatLeftAligned(String prefix, int padding, String suffix) {
        return String.format("%-" + padding + "s %s:", prefix, suffix);
    }

    public static String formatRightAligned(String prefix, int padding, String suffix) {
        return String.format("%" + padding + "s %s:", prefix, sufix);
    }

}
```

If you want more control over the padding...You could even use varargs for the methods allow the format methods to determine the padding amount it self, and return an array of `String`s formatted to these requirements, as an idea

**Updated**

If you need both the suffix and prefix to be padded, it might be easier to pad them separately, for example...

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("XXXX", 4), padLeft("??", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("XXXX", 4), padRight("??", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("XXXX", 4), padRight("??", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("XXXX", 4), padLeft("??", 2)));

        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("YY", 4), padLeft("??", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("YY", 4), padRight("??", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("YY", 4), padRight("??", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("YY", 4), padLeft("??", 2)));

        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("XXXX", 4), padLeft("?", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("XXXX", 4), padRight("?", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("XXXX", 4), padRight("?", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("XXXX", 4), padLeft("?", 2)));

        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("YY", 4), padLeft("?", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("YY", 4), padRight("?", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padLeft("YY", 4), padRight("?", 2)));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s:", padRight("YY", 4), padLeft("?", 2)));

    }

    public static String padLeft(String value, int padding) {
        return String.format("%-" + padding + "s", value);
    }

    public static String padRight(String value, int padding) {
        return String.format("%" + padding + "s", value);
    }
}
```

Don't forget you can compound formats...

```
XXXX 词语:
XXXX 词语:
XXXX 词语:
XXXX 词语:
YY   词语:
  YY 词语:
YY   词语:
  YY 词语:
XXXX 人 :
XXXX  人:
XXXX  人:
XXXX 人 :
YY   人 :
  YY  人:
YY    人:
  YY 人 :
```

**Updated**

Focus on each of the formatting needs separatly, for example....

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s=\"%s\"", padLeft("XXXX", 4), "词语"));
System.out.println(String.format("%s=\"%s\"", padLeft("YY", 4), "人"));
```

Here, we format the "XXXX" and "YY" separately from what it's displaying, this prints...

```
XXXX="词语"
YY  ="人"
```

**Updated**

Fonts play a VERY big role in this, for example...

[image: FontWidth]

As you can see, the chinese characters expand beyond the "normal" character width, and in fact, each chinese character has it's own width...

**Updated**

If you're using Swing, you take advantage of it's inbuilt (limited) support for HTML, for example

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
sb.append("<html><table><tr><td align=left>");
sb.append("词语");
sb.append("</td><td align=left>");
sb.append("end");
sb.append("</td></tr><tr><td align=left>");
sb.append("人");
sb.append("</td><td align=left>");
sb.append("end");
sb.append("</td></tr></table>");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb);
```

[image: FontWidth OptionPane]

Comment: Hi, what if I hope the max lengh(larger length of this two String) to be a param? Can I just replace the -4 in to "-"+n?

Comment: @Jaskey Yeah, didn't think about that at first, but I updated to include a variable padding value

Comment: Thank you ! I test it, it work if the XXX is English, but when I use XXXX="卧底", YYYY="人"，it did not alight right.. Would you please try that?

Comment: Add a padding to the suffix ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Excellent .

Comment: @Yubi Yeah, got a little carried away :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer You had answered my many questions here. I know you are brilliant. I wish could see you in real.

Comment: @Yubi I just borrow from other peoples brilliance ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer , I see your update, but you miss understand me. I am not saying that the "词语" be replaced by "人"。 actually, the "词语" is a constant and it will not be changed, what I need most is that th e XXXX and the YY will be aligned. So if I use "XXXX", and "YY", your answser works perfectly fine with n=4. But when I use XXXX="卧底"， YY="人"。 with n=2, it did not work. I guess it is relative to the spaces cost difference between chinese and english.

Comment: @Jaskey you would also need to used a fixed width sized chinese font.

Comment: Separate your format requirements, you need to pad "XXXX" and "YY" then add "="卧底"" or "="人" to that result as you need ;)

Comment: I am Sorry I still not make myself clear, I will update it to the answer with part of your answer, and let you know what I am facing.

Comment: Don't modify the answer, modify the question ;)

Comment: Would you please see my answer, which explains my problem?

Comment: I saw your last update, so do you mean I do not have way to align Chinese?

Comment: Not if you're using Swing to display them, this is a really neat feature and I've used a LOT to do formatted output like this in the past (and probably into the future).  Let the HTML table take care of it for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60142/discussion-between-jaskey-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60143/discussion-between-jaskey-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

```
public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
}
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

especially:

> %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion

Comment: I will try that now, would you  also explain what "%1$" +n means ?

Comment: be careful I edited it `return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  `

Comment: I guess you are right But I tried passing  the word and the n=8 and it does not work. What is n means?

Comment: @Jaskey `n` will be the number of spaces to pad `s` out to if it's length is less than `n`

Comment: @Jaskey if you pass in n=8 then the format will be %1$-8s, so you use it like `padLeft ("XX", 4) + "词语:";`

Comment: Please check my answer to this to explain the further problem when facing with chinese padding. Also, I notice that you advice for a fixed width for chinese font. Would you please update your answer for both two Language font to be fitted?

Answer (score 0):

Than you for @MadProgrammer's answer which is working fine for English padding. And I pick some part of it up.

Here is the result test:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String english1="xxxx";
    String english2="yy";

    String chinese1="卧底的";
    String chinese2="人";

    int n=english1.length()>english2.length()? english1.length():english2.length();
    int m=chinese1.length()>chinese2.length()? chinese1.length():chinese2.length();
    System.out.println(padRight(english1,n)+"end");
    System.out.println(padRight(english2,n)+"end");
    System.out.println(padRight(chinese1,m)+"end");
    System.out.println(padRight(chinese2,m)+"end");
}

 public static String padRight(String value, int padding) {
        return String.format("%" + padding + "s", value);
 }
```

The output is :

```
xxxxend
  yyend
卧底的end
   人end
```

Notice that the chinse padding is still have some problem

Comment: As Scary Wombat pointed out, you're going to need a fixed width font to make this display correctly...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, so, what should this width to be? and how is the code to be changed?

Comment: The width is (semi) irrelevant.  You need a font where each character is the same size (width) - hence, fixed width font

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I am sorry I still not understand you. Would you please take my second case to your answer and updated it ?

Comment: For example, if I jump to the console and run it, it looks formated (I can't see the chinese characters, because the console font doesn't support it, but the format looks fine).  If I run it in my IDE, the formatting comes off because the font is variable width

Comment: Are you outputting this to a text display or graphically (like through Swing)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I do test the answer in my ecplise IDE, so do you mean  the solution will be working fine in the PROD?

Comment: @MadProgrammer , I tried      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, padRight(chinese1,m)+"end\n"+padRight(chinese2,n)+"end");  and it is still not aligned

Comment: you could using tabs instead, but you will also face some trouble.  Or use an embedded table

Comment: @Jaskey Trying using a HTML table within the `JOptionPane`

Comment: @Jaskey Have a look at the last couple of updates I posted to my answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer What if I am not using Swing. I just need to print it to the console in some way. :(